# Zend framework - is there a validator for multiple checkboxes?

Tags: zend-framework

I want 2 checkboxes for yes/no answers, and require that either one be ticked. Is there a built-in validator for a 'group' of checkboxes?

Comment: FYI, for a yes/no answer you should use the radio element and not checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't.

But you can do something like this in your form. Manually inside your form class, extend the isValid method to check that at least checkbox_1 or checkbox_2 is ticket. And you should do what Adrian said use radio instead. But the principle is the same.

```
<?php 

class App_Your_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
         ... Your stuff ...
    }

    public function isValid($data)
    {
        $isValid = parent::isValid($data);

        if ($this->getValue('checkbox_1') != '1' && $this->getValue('checkbox_2') != '1') {
             $this->getElement('checkbox_1')->setErrors(array('You  have to set check at least chexbkox_1 or checkbox 2'));
             $isValid = false;
        }

        return $isValid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the radio element you only need `setRequired(true)`. Same actually works for the `MultiCheckbox` Zend element.

```
$element->setRequired(true);
```